# Filtering a string from arrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, filtering

I have an ArrayList with student grades and I want to filter students with the given grade letter. For example, if the user enters A the table must show all the students with the F grade. But the problem is it does not filter it.

```
  static List<Assign2> studentList = new ArrayList<>();


    String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Which grade do you want to filter?");

            List<Assign2> remaining = new ArrayList<>(studentList);
            for(int i=0;i<remaining.size();i++){
                if(remaining.get(i).getLetterGrade()!=letter){

                    remaining.remove(i);
                }
            }

            table(remaining);
```

Comment: What is the format of your letter grades ? `String? char?` Or you sure that the grades are not all `A`'s ? ^^

Comment: Side note: remove the if letter is “A” etc and just check the value of the user input in the loop, otherwise you need many loops, one for each letter.

Comment: use a debugger to see the values live while being added.

Comment: also, if this is your code, then the studentList is empty. Obviously there is more stuff going on that we cannot see.

Comment: @JoachimHuet The letter grade must be of type `String` since there is no `contains()` method for `char`

Comment: String @JoachimHuet

Comment: no at first I add students of course but I skip that part then this code is happening @isaace

Comment: I understand, but your code looks ok so there must be something wrong somewhere. A debugger would help you immediately.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is in the `studentList`? A screenshot of the debugoutput of the filled `studentList` would be helpful.

Comment: Kfbefyg  GLKBH  65144080991  73   45    8   87  66    55.8    D+   assume that there are 5 students like this with different letter grades, quiz results... in the studentList @melanzane

Comment: @Ekin and the `getLetterGrade()` would return the string D+ in the example above?

Comment: print the size of your sList before starting the loop > print the grade before adding the object to  the sList and print the size of the sList before calling table(sList); please share your results.

Comment: yes it gives D+ @melanzane

Comment: sList before size:0
last slist size0 it gives this but in arrayList there is a student with D grade (I tried with the letter grade) @isaace

Comment: are you saying that when you passed the sList to table the size was 0? and it still showed it? if yes then the problem is in your table method.

Comment: I am going to edit my question and add my table method to so you can see @isaace

Comment: sList before size:0
print the gradeD+
print the gradeD+
print the gradeD+
print the gradeD+
last slist size4 now it give me this but it shows the original table but the bigger problem is I asked to filter D not D+ @isaace

Comment: I correct the D+ part but still it shows the original table @isaace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
    List<Strudents> sList = studentList.stream()
            .peek(s -> System.out.println(s.getLetterGrade())) // just for debugging purpose
            .filter(s -> s.getLetterGrade().contains("A")) // why not equals? Is it one letter only?
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on what i understood in your question. 
try like this. for each student you need to check if he hasn't the entered grade letter, if so you add him to the list.

```
   String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Which grade do you want to filter?"); 
                for(int i=0;i<studentList.size();i++){
                       if(!studentList.get(i).getLetterGrade().equalsIgnoreCase(letter)){
                        sList.add(studentList.get(i));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: still it gives the original array not filtered one

Answer (score 1):

You could use following java8 snippet to filter out all grades which are not equal to the input:

```
 // create copy
 List<Assign2> remaining = new ArrayList<>(studentList);

// remove all that do not have the input grade
remaining.removeIf(e -> !e.getLetterGrade().equals(letter));
```

The above code first creates a copy of the original list. And then uses that copy, to remove all students which don't have the grade the user entered.

**Note:** the original list will still be the same. So it still contains all Students

Comment: sorry my mistake but still  it gives an empty table

Comment: @Ekin can you confirm that the inputs are correct and validated? That the list has values in it? That the values in the list are coreect? There can be so many cases for errora

Comment: Yes I can confirm forget about my previous comment eclipse did not give any error but for the output the table is empty

Comment: I made some modifications now it shows the table but for example I want A it gives A but also sometimes it gives C or D

Comment: @Ekin Do you test if the user input is uppercase? Length of 1? And also the same for the strings stored in the objects from the studentList

Comment: It takes the size of the C- 2 how can I make it one

Comment: @Ekin Use `letter = letter.trim()` which removes all whitespace from the start and end

Comment: I tried with D in the output it gives both D and D+

Comment: @Ekin Are you using equals or contains?

Comment: Equals but it does not matter tried also with the contains

Comment: I can't test it on my own, but you are sure that the above mentioned causes of error have been taken care of?

Comment: yes it shows something but it is wrong when I ask the letter A it gives me A and C

Comment: my code is like this now:String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Which grade do you want to filter?");
   letter=letter.trim();
   List<Assign2> remaining = new ArrayList<>(studentList);
   for(int i=0;i<remaining.size();i++){
    if(!remaining.get(i).getLetterGrade().equals(letter)){
     remaining.remove(i); 
    }
   }
   table(remaining);

Comment: @Ekin and what exactly doesn't work about that snippet? Have you debugged it? Has the remaining list only the elements it should contain?

Comment: No for example when I want to filter the letter D the output is sometimes letter D and letter D+ sometimes just D+ it does not work right

Comment: There is something seriously wrong about the code because it assumes that all letters are the last students letter grade so it can not delete it but eclipse does not give an error

Answer (score 1):

You can do some pre calculation. Like you can group all the students whose grade are same and put them in hashmap. When you will get an query just get the list of the students from the map.

Another option with out using

> studentList.get(i).getLetterGrade().contains("A")

use

> studentList.get(i).getLetterGrade().equalsIgnoreCase("A")

Comment: it gives me this and I am not sure  what is it: Assign2[Vgfg,0,23,0x0,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]